OIDC + ADFS: How to get ID token?
I have an OpenID Connect client implementation (code flow), which works fine with Google, MS 365 and most other providers.
It does not work, however, with on-premise ADFS, because its userinfo endpoint does not return email field.
I was suggested to extract it from id_token, which must be a JWT, but I have not success with it.
My current query parameters to authorize endpoint:
response_type=code
client_id=cf5b770f-4c33-462d-b7e0-xxxxxxxx
scope=openid email profile
redirect_uri=http://myserver/openid_auth/oauth_redirect
state=59b2f1924e8d21fb97fa73cee43ab973
access_type=offline

Unlike Google, MS does not return id_token with access_token by default. So I set response_type="code id_token".
After that I got an error: "The 'nonce' parameter is mandatory for Open ID requests when the response type includes 'id_token'".
I added
nonce=ufouhfoiwehfweihfoehfoef

which seemed to turn my flow into implicit flow, because I got the redirect url with parameters within anchor:
/openid_auth/oauth_redirect#code=xxxxxxxxx&state=59b2f1924e8d21fb97fa73cee43ab973

Could anybody please advise me on how to correctly retrieve id token containing user login or email using OIDC code flow?
